# Should 'setup_postdata()' be reset with 'wp_reset_postdata()'?

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, wp-reset-postdata

Starting with an example makes more sense, so here's an example function:

```
function seo_meta_tags() {
    global $post;

    if( is_singular() ) {

        setup_postdata( $post );

        $description = str_replace( '... <a class="read-more" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Cont. reading &rarr;</a>', '...', get_the_excerpt() );

        wp_reset_postdata();

        echo '<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="' . $description . '">';

    }
}
```

***NOTE:** The code is only to give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish and not exactly how I am doing it.*

Now coming to the point, should `setup_postdata( $post )` be closed with `wp_reset_postdata()` as shown in the example?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: @tf Why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `setup_postdata` is *messing* with global variables that might be (most probably: **are**) used by other loops (including *The Loop*), you should always reset these variables to what they should be—according to the main query (i.e., what WordPress thinks the user wanted in the first place).
In addition, `setup_postdata` is provided with (a reference to) the `$post` global, which might be altered afterwards.

So, yes, [`setup_postdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) should be accompanied by [`wp_reset_postdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

[As you can see in the code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3849), the `reset_postdata` function is, in fact, calling `setup_postdata` on the *original* `$post` object.